# SquishIt : How to minfy CSS files inside asp.net default theme and Javascript files from asp:ScriptManager?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, minify, squishit

I like this library but could not find any info on how to use SquishIt with asp.net themes and the scriptmanager? The examples below work on the masterpage as long as you have the css links and js links on the same masterpage. How do you use SquishIt with the css files stored on App_Themes/Default/ folder? and the scripts inside asp:ScriptManager? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<%= Bundle.JavaScript()
    .Add("~/js/jquery-1.4.2.js")
    .Add("~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.1.js")
    .Render("~/js/combined_#.js")
%>

<%= Bundle.Css()
    .Add("~/css/reset.css")
    .Add("~/css/text.css")
    .Add("~/css/960.css")
    .Render("~/css/combined_#.css")
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are treated as Resources and compiled into the DLL.
I believe you have no influence on that, lest you customize the build process, but I believe you need TFS and/or a build server for such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If these are compiled into the DLL you should be able to treat them as embedded resources and include them via .AddEmbeddedResource.  I know for some of the other Microsoft-provided stuff we had to add .AddRootEmbeddedResource because they are namespaced differently (see [this issue](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/issues/171)).  But between these two methods I suspect you'll be able to get it working.  Might just require some fiddling to find the right name to use.

Comment: thanks for your help. do you have an actual example of how to do that? I would like to see the syntax of how to use squishit to: "treat them as embedded resources and include them via .AddEmbeddedResource." Not sure if those are compiled into the dll. In debug mode I don't see any dlls created from the css/js. When you look at source code on browser all css and js files appear intact. How do you use SquishIt with the css files stored on App_Themes/Default/ folder? and the scripts inside asp:ScriptManager?

Comment: If the comment above is correct, I would expect them to be included in your site's DLL in the bin directory.  Take a look at [this test](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/blob/master/SquishIt.Tests/CSSBundleTests.cs#L368-383) for usage.  The first argument is the path used to render individual files for debugging and the second is the path to the resource.  [This test](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/blob/master/SquishIt.Tests/CSSBundleTests.cs#L407-423) demonstrates using an embedded resource that doesn't use the normal namespacing convention.